# How to make a simpler formula for multiple if / isnumber

Tags: excel, excel-formula

basically I got 10+ columns of data and i only want the first column that contain a number, other then the super long way of

```
=if(isnumber(B1),B1,if(isnumber(C1),C1,if(isnumber(D1),D1.....
```

is there a more simple way to do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B1:K1)/(ISNUMBER(B1:K1)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! i kinda understand the formula except the "1" at the end. Can you please clarify a little but on what is that 1 doing :)?

Comment: The aggregate is in SMALL form and the `1` is the `k` value.  that means it returns the 1st smallest column that has a number in it.